# AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer Video layer rotating but image doesn't

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

[image: After capturing image, it returns to portrait][image: Video capture layer which shows 180 degree rotation before capturing]

I'm apply Orientation (e.g.:- `AVCaptureVideoOrientationLandscapeLeft,AVCaptureVideoOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)` on object of `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer`, Its rotating the video layer perfectly, but captured image always displaying in Portrait mode.

Note: App doesn't have any orientation, its camera setting feature that rotate (0,90,180,270 degree) capture preview layer.

Transformation on captured image not working.

Comment: Show your code. I can solve your problem.